# VB.Net Program should auto update

Tags: vb.net, auto-update

I have a program written in `VB.Net` and this program is supposed to auto update. I already found how to download the new file and unzip it, problem is I cannot overwrite the file as long its in execution. How is this done normally? I thought about an "updater" on a separate exe but that would have the same problem, I couldn't update the updater when I make some changes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply close the old program.

Keep the separate updater program, then when you want to update your old program, get the updater to close the old program, then download the new version of your app. For example,

Updater program,

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Do While True
        Dim client As New Net.WebClient
        Dim newVersion As String = client.DownloadString("http://www.myWebsite.com/updates/latestVersion.txt")
        If newVersion <> IO.File.ReadAllText("Your programs file location") Then
            For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
                If p.ProcessName = "your program's process name" Then 'If you don't know what your program's process name is, simply run your program, run windows task manager, select 'processes' tab, scroll down untill you find your programs name.
                    p.Kill()
                End If
            Next
            IO.File.Delete("old program file location")
            client.DownloadFile("http://www.myWebsite.com/updates/12.05.2013.exe", "where ever you want to download your new program to (file location)")
            client.Dispose()
        End If
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(300000) 'freeze thread for 5 mins...
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! just 2 small questions: how can i update the updater? :) why do you freeze for 5 mins?

Comment: Your welcome, 1) Get the old updater to download the new updater, once the new updater has been downloaded run the new updater, get the new updater to close the old updater (if it's running) and delete it, 2) If you look carefully you'll see that the program is running in an infinite loop, so the 5 min freeze basically stops the program from checking for new updates every few milliseconds, you could remove the loop so that the program only checks once it's executed, or change how long the program freezes.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but what I do is, when I am within my main program, I copy rename the current updater, and then call out to the renamed updater like so:

(note, code has been simplified for explanation and illustration)

```
FileCopy("MyUpdater.exe", "~MyUpdater.exe") ' rename the updater
Shell("~MyUpdater.exe") ' start the updater
END ' close the current program
```

Then when your updater does it's job, it will update MyUpdater.exe as well as everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a ClickOnce deployment, and host it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

simple solution,
just divide the exe file source code into multiple DLL file(like divide in terms of modules) and have the main exe to execute the dll code like 
 
       
 sub MDImainEXE_load()
        
  DLL.function like that
       
   end sub 
  
 
 and you can use the same method for update exe 
send new main exe with configuration and DLL,configuration file will contain DLL names to update,if update exe has to update then name that DLL as argument to use because update exe will not contain code just use function from DLL file name from configuration file arguments. 
 
       
   sub updateEXE_load()
       
   DLL.function like that
       
   end sub

if confused then ask what confused.

Comment: honestly all confused me.. (pretty green here) the application is made up from a single exe file.. nothing more

Comment: You do know that Visual Studio has this functionality built-in, right?

Comment: what confused you and how much you get it or planning to implement it so that we can get your idea of implementation

Comment: @Just me [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19623/Adding-automatic-updates-to-your-program-Part-1)

Comment: @Douglas, yes i know but i dont like it. It gives more trouble then its Worth.. vinod maybe the way your are explaining.. having trouble following you and understand what you mean. thanks! ps: watching the link now

Comment: I thought you were making a app with multiple dependencies, lol. If you're making a single exe app then simply follow the instructions i gave.

Comment: @Just me can you give a little bit of more info like is your application database based or simple apllication , client server based ,how the updater will update etc etc so that i can give you a more proper answer as per your condition.Sorry to confuse you,but i answer is a bit more ERP based generic solution where you can change your method of updation as well as main app.if you need more explaination ,feel free to ask even i have faced similar situation.

Comment: what @Sam have done is a simple answer,do as per his instruction and in code at application startup just check if copy directory or you can name it updater directory is empty or not.if empty then continue as normal else if not empty then start the updater exe on another process and then exit the main exe like<code>updater.start()<br>Me.exit()</code>after that the updater exe will replace the exe from copy or updater directory to main directory replacing old main exe with new new exe after that give a message<code>messagebox.show("Exe have been updated.Please restart the application")</code>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like **Create A Dump File for a Running Process**

You see it [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?499638-RESOLVED-Create-A-Dump-File-for-a-Running-Process)

But it depends on your VB version....

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in several application and solved this with a simple .bat file.
In you myapp.exe:

1. Download the updated exe to %TEMP%.
2. Write a bat file to %TEMP%\UpdateMyApp.bat:

```
(Wait for a couple of seconds for the current app to close)
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 -w 3000 > NUL
move %TEMP%\myapp.exe %PATH_TO_EXE%\myapp.exe /Y
%PATH_TO_EXE%\myapp.exe
```

3. execute %TEMP%\UpdateMyApp.bat from you app.
4. Close app immediatly.