# VB.Net Autoupdater that overwrites current open program?

Tags: vb.net, auto-update

I have a program written in VB.Net and i want the program to auto-update. I've tried a few methods but without success. How do i make a second .exe file that will launch with the program itself on start to check if there is a new version and if there is download and overwrite current program, else just load the program as usual?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net Program should auto update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636096/vb-net-program-should-auto-update)

Comment: I am not that user and I do not understand how to implement that. Check what I've wrote for the second .exe file please

Comment: If the only problem you have is "how do I start another EXE", that's solved by reading the documentation for e.g. System.Diagnostics.Process.Start.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework offers this functionality built-in through the ClickOnce installer. It allows you to update the executable on the server and when the program is next run, it will compare version numbers and download and update the local executable.

You write that you want an additional program that will check whether there is an update available, this will prove to be more difficult to maintain, as you will have to pass the current version number to the updater program to check if it needs to be updated (and what if you need to update the updater program?).