# Update software function doesn't work if software is already open

Tags: vb.net

I've a function that check update for my application. I've two mode for execute this function, in the first time that the application's start and in the tooltip menu. If I execute the software for the first time all working good, the update is found , but if I press on my button in the tooltip menu the same function (the exact function) not working. In particular the update is found but the software for download it (infinity blue) doesn't start.
This is the function:

```
Dim MyAppName As String = "Sund.exe"
        Dim url As String = "www.site.com/update/" & "FileUpdates371.php"
        Dim pageRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim pageResponse As WebResponse = pageRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim filelist As String : Dim Mainlist As String
        Using r As New StreamReader(pageResponse.GetResponseStream())
            filelist = r.ReadToEnd
            If Not IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "Updates") Then
                IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "Updates", filelist)
            End If
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "Updates")
            Mainlist = sr.ReadToEnd
            Dim FileLines() As String = filelist.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            Dim MainLines() As String = Mainlist.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            If Not Mainlist = filelist And Not FileLines.Length < MainLines.Length Then
                Dim answer As DialogResult
                answer = MessageBox.Show("Update available", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                If answer = vbYes Then
                    Dim App As New Process
                    App.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath & "\" & "InfinityBlue.exe"
                    App.StartInfo.Arguments = "Update|" & MyAppName & "|" & url
                    App.Start()
                    Me.Close()
                End If
            End If
        End Using
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "InfinityBlueUpdate.exe") Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "InfinityBlue.exe", FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "InfinityBlueUpdate.exe", "InfinityBlue.exe")
        End If
```

I've also tried to catch the exception and there isn't exception. Why happean this?

Comment: you cannot overwrite a file in use, including an exe **if** you even have permission to write to that folder

Comment: Uhm OK, but there is a solution for fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net Program should auto update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636096/vb-net-program-should-auto-update)

Comment: write two programs. one to update and also launch the other. if no update found, just launch.

Comment: Okay. But I already have two programs, the only problem is that the uploader is started in the second case by a tooltip function..

Comment: Not the answer, just a `tip`: **avoid unnecessary string concatenations**, since they are **bad for performances**. I.e.: `"\" & "Updates"` should be `"\Updates"`